# How to get R plot window size?

Tags: r, plot

How can I get the size of the plot window in R? I've been using xwininfo, but there must be a function or variable in R to extract the current plot height and width.

*UPDATE*

This works as a `savePlot()` replacement if you don't have Cairo support and you want to export plots to Windows or other 100 dpi devices:

```
dev.copy(png, "myplot.png", width=dev.size("px")[1], height=dev.size("px")[2], 
         res=100, bg="transparent")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `dev.size`. Here is an example:

```
 x11()
 plot(1)
 dev.size("in")
  [1] 6.989583 6.992017

 dev.size("cm")
  [1] 17.75354 17.75972
```

This gets the size of your plotting window in inches and centimeters.

Similar for a `png` device:

```
 png('kk.png')
 dev.size("in")
 [1] 6.666667 6.666667
```

Does this help you?

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned , using some `par` settings you can control control the size and the location of the plot regions. But those parameters can be a little bit confusing.( at least for me), I tried to resume some of them in this plot precising the units of each parameter. 
[image]

PS: the original graphics is adpated from [Paul Murrel Book: R graphics.](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to par()$fin.
HTH